# Using $this when not in object context php. Function decode BLOB datatype

Tags: php, innodb

```js
<?php

include("config.php"); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// connect to the mysql server
$link = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass)
or die ("nonono ".mysql_error());

// select the database
mysql_select_db($db_name)
or die ("nonono".mysql_error());
class data {
 public function getchardata($charname,$opt){
            $char = $this->myfetch($this->myquery("select decode(Column1,'decodekey') FROM TableName where Name = '$charname' "));
            $blob = $this->strToHex($char[0]);
        if($opt =='level')return hexdec(substr($blob,52,2));
        if($opt =='coin')return hexdec(substr($blob,26,2).substr($blob,24,2).substr($blob,22,2).substr($blob,20,2));
        if($opt =='pet')return hexdec(substr($blob,66,2).substr($blob,64,2).substr($blob,62,2).substr($blob,60,2));
        if($opt =='credit')return hexdec(substr($blob,74,2).substr($blob,72,2).substr($blob,70,2).substr($blob,68,2));
        if($opt =='exp')return hexdec(substr($blob,44,2).substr($blob,42,2).substr($blob,40,2).substr($blob,38,2).substr($blob,36,2));

    }
}
?>
```

I have problem with this function: Using $this when not in object context.
Anyone can help please?
updated

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: First It will connect to database where is storing my characters data. So I want it get data from the table that data had been encoded on its column.
I'm using this function to retry data from table but I'm new on PHP.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are calling the function, including the database connection initialization?

Comment: Can you post the whole class?

Comment: full code uploaded bro! Appreciate your kindness

Comment: Do _NOT_ use the `mysql_*` API; switch to either `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to pass $this as parameter of your method/function.

So to call your function you will use something like : `getchardata($charname,$opt,$this)` and inside your function you refer is as `$_this`.

```
    <?php

include("config.php"); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// connect to the mysql server
$link = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass)
or die ("nonono ".mysql_error());

// select the database
mysql_select_db($db_name)
or die ("nonono".mysql_error());
class data {
    public function getchardata($charname,$opt,&$_this){
            $char = $_this->myfetch($this->myquery("select decode(Column1,'decodekey') FROM TableName where Name = '$charname' "));
            $blob = $_this->strToHex($char[0]);
        if($opt =='level')return hexdec(substr($blob,52,2));
        if($opt =='coin')return hexdec(substr($blob,26,2).substr($blob,24,2).substr($blob,22,2).substr($blob,20,2));
        if($opt =='pet')return hexdec(substr($blob,66,2).substr($blob,64,2).substr($blob,62,2).substr($blob,60,2));
        if($opt =='credit')return hexdec(substr($blob,74,2).substr($blob,72,2).substr($blob,70,2).substr($blob,68,2));
        if($opt =='exp')return hexdec(substr($blob,44,2).substr($blob,42,2).substr($blob,40,2).substr($blob,38,2).substr($blob,36,2));

    }
}
?>
```